# Pandas: create column with partial string search result

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. I'm searching `df1['comment']` for the partial strings in `df2['label']` using the following line of code, which returns a new column `df1['match']` with True/False values.

`df1['match'] = df1['comment'].str.contains('|'.join(df2['label'].values), na=False)`

Now I don't only want the the True/False `df1['match']` column but also a column that shows which of the partial strings from `df2['label']` was found in `df1['match']`. I tried using something like

`if df1['comment'].str.contains('|'.join(df2['label'].values), na=False) == True:`

```
df1['label_item'] = df2['label'].values
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I also feel like writing an if condition is probably not the right thing to do and that there is probably some kind of shortcut to solve this question.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df1['label_item'] = df1['comment'].str.findall(f'({"|".join(df2.label)})').str.join(',')
```